# How to display the function name into the function itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell, busybox

How to dispaly the function name into the function?

```
#!/bin/sh
toto()
{
    echo "$something"
}

toto
```

the above code should display

```
toto
```

I m using bash linux from busybox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$FUNCNAME` to do so.

```
$ toto()
> {
> echo "this function name is $FUNCNAME"
> }
$ toto
this function name is toto
```

Comment: this works for my ubuntu shell but it does not work for BusyBox bash

Comment: Uhms I am afraid it is not possible, then. See http://www.mail-archive.com/slitaz@lists.tuxfamily.org/msg01550.html

Comment: I believe BusyBox uses `ash`, not `bash`. `FUNCNAME` was added to `bash` in version 2.0, so it's unlikely to be a version issue.